# Using argparse argument names as variable names

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use name of arguments in argparse as variable names. Now I'm doing something like:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('a')
parser.add_argument('b')
parser.add_argument('c')
parser.add_argument('--d')
parser.add_argument('--e')

args = parser.parse_args()

a = args.a
b = args.b
c = args.c
d = args.d
e = args.e
```

But this is so inefficient and I may end up with over 10 arguments in total. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Any reason to not use `dict`? Use can just access `args['a']`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that this is a very discouraged behavior, but if you really need to do it,

```py
globals().update(args.__dict__)
```

will update your global namespace.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: @Chris, yes, I agree very much, thus "this is a very discouraged behavior." But if one has a convincing reason to do so, with enough consideration, I'm just suggesting a way to do it. (And I wouldn't count the OP's "saving typing" as a convincing reason...)

Comment: Thanks guys. I will definitely use it with caution. It's only an ad hoc script.

Answer (score 0):

This is best I have found to reduce lines of code when renaming arg vars:

```
a,b,c,d,e = args.a, args.b, args.c, args.d, args.e
```

For me it's an acceptable solution, where no additional processing is required on an arg var.